# Terminate vbscript after x minutes

Tags: time, vbscript

I am working on a script with vbscript, and I would like it to terminate itself after x number of minutes.

I was thinking something like grabbing the time when the script starts and then keeping the whole thing in a loop until the time is x number of minutes after the start time, but I need it to keep checking in the background, and not just wait until a loop is complete.

I want a message or something that notifies the user they took too long, which I can do myself.

Is there any way to keep track of the time in the background, or will it be a bit of a drawn-out process to determine it?

Answer (score 7):

Re-launching the script with `//T:xx` as suggested by [Ekkehard.Horner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15031657/1630171) is probably your best option. Another, slightly different, approach could look like this:

```
Const Timeout = 4 'minutes

timedOut = False

If WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("relaunch") Then
  'your code here
Else
  limit = DateAdd("n", Timeout, Now)
  cmd = "wscript.exe """ & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ /relaunch"
  Set p = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec(cmd)
  Do While p.Status = 0
    If Now < limit Then
      WScript.Sleep 100
    Else
      On Error Resume Next  'to ignore "invalid window handle" errors
      p.Terminate
      On Error Goto 0
      timedOut = True
    End If
  Loop
End If

If timedOut Then WScript.Echo "Script timed out."
```

You'd still be re-launching the script, but in this case it's your script killing the child process, not the script interpreter.

Comment: +1 for a solution that takes into account the spec 'a message ... that notifies the user they took too long' (and does not make you sick).

Comment: Nice idea, just one thing bother me, I get "Invalid window handle" at line `p.Terminate`. If `cmd` go with "cscript.exe" or "%comspec% /c wscript" then works fine.

Comment: @PanayotKarabakalov I noticed that this happens sometimes. Not sure what exactly causes it, though. Since the child process is terminated anyway it's probably best to simply ignore it and move the notification outside the loop. I updated my sample code accordingly.

Comment: I thought that `Exec` expect visible window, but error traping is a nice fix (+1).

Answer (score 4):

Here is another short and elegant solution which allows to terminate both the script and the external executable ran asynchronously, via `WScript.Timeout`

```vbs
Option Explicit

Dim oSmallWrapperWshExec

WScript.Timeout = 7
Set oSmallWrapperWshExec = New cSmallWrapperWshExec
' Some code here
MsgBox "Waiting timeout" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "You may close notepad manually and/or press OK to finish script immediately"

Class cSmallWrapperWshExec

    Private oWshShell
    Private oWshExec

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()

        Set oWshShell = CreateObject("WSCript.Shell")
        With oWshShell
            Set oWshExec = .Exec("notepad")
            .PopUp "Launched executable", 2, , 64
        End With

    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Terminate()

        On Error Resume Next
        With oWshShell
            If oWshExec.Status <> 0 Then
                .PopUp "Executable has been already terminated", 2, , 64
            Else
                oWshExec.Terminate
                .PopUp "Terminated executable", 2, , 64
            End If
        End With

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Ah, you're using a class destructor for terminating the external program. Clever. I like it.

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate all of the answers here, but they are more complicated than I wanted to get in to.

I was very surprised to find out that there is a way to do it built into `WScript`.

```
WScript.Timeout = x_seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cscript
Usage: CScript scriptname.extension [option...] [arguments...]

Options:
 //B         Batch mode: Suppresses script errors and prompts from displaying
 //D         Enable Active Debugging
 //E:engine  Use engine for executing script
 //H:CScript Changes the default script host to CScript.exe
 //H:WScript Changes the default script host to WScript.exe (default)
 //I         Interactive mode (default, opposite of //B)
 //Job:xxxx  Execute a WSF job
 //Logo      Display logo (default)
 //Nologo    Prevent logo display: No banner will be shown at execution time
 //S         Save current command line options for this user
 **//T:nn      Time out in seconds:  Maximum time a script is permitted to run**
 //X         Execute script in debugger
 //U         Use Unicode for redirected I/O from the console
```

**Update:**

To help people who downvote a plain (and to the point) citation of cscript.exe's usage message (how can that be wrong?) to see the light through @PanayotKarabakalov's smoke screen:

The claim:

> using //T switch not guarantee real time accuracy
>
> that all 5 Echo command executed, even if the Sleep time between them
>   is 1.5 second and the //T is set to 4

The evidence:

The script is restarted via:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "WScript " & _
    Chr(34) & WScript.ScriptFullName & _
    Chr(34) & " /T:4", 0, False
```

which does **not** contain the host-specific `//T` (as opposed to the script-specific `/T`) switch.

The (counter) argument:

Whatever way you start the first instance of the script (`//T` or no `//T`), the second/relaunched instance will never have a time out and will always run to the bitter end.

If you still have doubts, change the invocation in P.'s script to

```
 CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "WScript //T:4 " & _
```

and try it out.

Comment: Would I just have the script and relaunch itself with those arguments? 

I need the timeout to be from within the script itself.

Comment: @MattMiller - relaunch or use a 'master' script that calculates the time out and starts the 'slave'.

Comment: So, essentially there is no way to do it within the same script?

Comment: @MattMiller Correct. VBScript does not support parallel processing.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner - Thanks for all your comments, as you helped me to find out my mistake! Cheers!